# Sublime Text (problem with start "Hello Python world"

Tags: python, sublimetext

Can't see a message: (Hello Python world!)

I work with "Sublime Text". - Tools - Build System - New Build System:

```
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
- Tools - Build:
and then I see a message:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in...
```

Could anybody help, please?

I tried to change commands, but it not help.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text raises this error when your file is not saved, it remains 'untitled'.

[image]

Save the file under some name and it should work.